# Cassandra SSTableLoad Memory leak issue

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I created a Cassandra Job which takes data from Oracle and creates SSTable files for the data. We were testing the performance of the Job when we ran into issues.

Whenever there is high volume of data being processed, SSTablewrite creates multiple Data.db files and then it runs into memory leak issue. Can anyone please help me understand what this issue is and how can we resolve it.

_search/testing_table/testing_poc-testing_table-tmp-ka-10-Index.db to /file_directoory/to_load/ss_tables/testing_table/testing_poc-testing_table-ka-10-Index.db
03:15:09.209 [Thread-2] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /file_directoory/to_load/ss_tables/testing_table/testing_poc-testing_table-tmp-ka-10-Data.db to /file_directoory/to_load/ss_tables/testing_table/testing_poc-testing_table-ka-10-Data.db
03:15:22.378 [Reference-Reaper:1] ERROR o.a.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@322fe601) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@1943860552:Memory@[7ffadc07c380..7ffadc07c3e4) was not released before the reference was garbage collected

Answer (score 1):

I Just got through this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9285.

So this is known issue and rather it does correct within itself.